# Possessive case when there are post nominal letters

Tags: writing-style

If a person's name comes with post nominal letters, e.g., John Smith PhD or Mary Green MD, which of the following is the correct/better way of forming the possessive?

(A): John Smith PhD's student; Mary Green MD's clcinc

(B): student of John Smith PhD; clinic of Mary Green MD

To me, style (A) sounds unnatural. So which is recommended?

Comment: This would be better on the English Language Learners Stack...

Comment: Two related questions on that stack are [Parenthesis and apostrophes](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/222298/315609), and [If a noun is followed by brackets, where should the apostrophe be placed to show possession?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/445177/315609). The overall answer in those questions is to try rephrasing in ways that avoid awkward constructions like (A) altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with:

Dr. Smith's student

and

Dr. Green's clinic